# How to connect to wifi in CentOS 7(CLI)(no GUI)?

Tags: centos, command-line, wifi

I had installed CentOS(CLI,minimal).it have no GUI.i want connect to WiFi but answers on askubuntu are not working.[image: see this screenshot].I want to know following:-

- How to turn WiFi on/off?
- How to get list of available WiFi connections?
- How to connect WiFi that i want to connect with?

Answer (score 19):

The best and easy option I like to use with CentOS is nmtui. (Ref: [Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-networking_config_using_nmtui))

***THIS IS NOT GUI, IT IS TUI (TEXT USER INTERFACE***)

First you have to install nmtui,

```
# yum install NetworkManager-tui
```

Then,

```
# nmtui
```

This will option up what you are after.

[image]

Now you can go to Edit connection and itwill list out all the available WiFi connections for you. Then you can select what you want and Activate/Deactivate what ever you want.

Comment: The question says CLI, no GUI.

Comment: Yes. I know the question says it is CLI that's where nmtui comes handy.  It is not a GUI it is TUI. (Text User Interface) this is a recommended method by Redhat. Look, there are two things we can think of. If the requirement is to configure Wifi manually using a command line this is the best and easiest option. Scripting is not possible with this though, I agree.

Comment: How can I install NetworkManager-tui without Wifi ??

Comment: Correct this is the million dollar question. :) Again you have two options. Easy method is connecting your device to a wired network normally to a network port (RJ45) in your wifi  router and do the configuration. ( I have written this here how to do this for Raspberry Pi http://namal.org/. this is same for other devices as well). Second option is download the nmtui rpm and dependencies manually and install using RPM. If you can tell the device you are using and the exact centOS version probably I could tell you what exactly you have to do.

Comment: Thanks! I had an issue on CentOS7 where I couldn't activate (from a GUI) a second, duplicate Wi-Fi NIC because there were configuration conflicts somewhere along the way that prevented from connecting. I came across this suggested answer and this solution worked out most elegantly and allowed me to activate it from commandline.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Just to add, 'nmtui' is already installed in my centos7-minimal installation so all you have to do is run 'nmtui'.

Comment: You may also need to install `NetworkManager-wifi` with its dependencies. This can be installed from your original installation media.

Comment: My Wi-Fi network shows up under "Edit a connection".  However, that connection doesn't show up under "Activate a connection".

Answer (score 13):

To run the `ifconfig` ... command , you should install the `net-tools` package.

Because the `net-tools` is deprecated there is the `ip` and `iw` commands which answer your question:

> How to turn WiFi on/off?

```
$ ip link set <interface> up
$ ip link set <interface> down
```

> How to get list of available WiFi connections?

```
$ iw dev <interface> scan | grep SSID
```

> How to connect WiFi that i want to connect with?

Create a `wpa_supplicant` configuration file with the following content:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
ap_scan=1
```

To add the SSID and the password, run:

```
$ wpa_passphrase "YOUR-SSID" YOUR-PASSWD >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

To connect run:

```
$ wpa_supplicant -i <interface> -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
dhclient <interface>
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning net-tools deprecation.

Comment: I follow these steps and it works but I need to run `dhclient wlo1` as a last step before I get a dhcp lease. I added `scan_ssid=1` to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. tks GAD3R! :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are running CentOS 7:
You may want to check if NetworkManager is already there available for you to use:

chkconfig NetworkManager on

service NetworkManager start

Issue command: nmtui

Go directly to "Active a connection" to check if you already can see your wireless network/wi-fi. If so, input your password.

You can also Edit a profile for the wi-fi you want to connect.

NOTE: if you cannot active a wi-fi, try the following:
After above steps: /etc/init.d/network restart
OR REBOOT/RESTART your box.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to see if the drivers for the card are installed by using `lspci -k`

And then to know if your interface is correctly detected and named you can use `ip link`
You can then try to bring up the interface with ifup

If the interface does not come up correctly it might be because you're missing a configuration file like `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface-name>`

Another alternative solution if it's something you only want to bring up once you can input the following commands :

```
ip link set dev <interface-name> up
wpa_supplicant -B -i <interface-name> -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhcpcd <interface-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my experience, for the following reasons:

1. If you got connected to Wifi network when you have installed CentOS 7.
2. After CentOS 7 entering into sleep mode OR accidental shutdown due to power drainage OR you have restarted & logged into CentOS 7

and if your wifi not working.

Don't install extra kernel module/do any tweaks/install any new packages

**Just shutdown and boot again in CentOS 7. Your wifi will start working again.**

This is what I realised after 6 hours of tweaks and tried everything out.