# CentOS 8 No Wi-Fi Adapter Found

Tags: centos, networking, usb, ethernet

Just installed CentOS 8 (with GUI) on a clean machine.

When accessing Settings>Wi-Fi I get the question mark with:

> No Wi-Fi Adapter Found
> Make sure you have a Wi-Fi adapter plugged and turned on

There's nothing wrong with the Bluetooth though.

In this machine, I don't have access to Ethernet connection, however I can plug a USB.

I have sudo access with this user.

---

**Edit 1**

[Just came across this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398049/226215).

I have [accessed here](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/centos-baseos-x86_64/) to download the following packages to a USB stick:

• NetworkManager-1.22.8-5.el8_2.x86_64.rpm

• NetworkManager-tui-1.22.8-5.el8_2.x86_64.rpm

• NetworkManager-libnm-1.22.8-5.el8_2.i686.rpm

• NetworkManager-libnm-1.22.8-5.el8_2.x86_64.rpm

• NetworkManager-wifi-1.22.8-5.el8_2.x86_64.rpm

Changed the directory to the USB stick and when trying to install one of the packages by using

```
rpm -Uhv $PackageName
```

I am always incurring in Failed dependencies errors.

Eg. When installing `NetworkManager-tui-1.22.8-5.el8_2.x86_64.rpm`, I get that I need the following dependencies:

- NetworkManager
- NetworkManager-libnm

If I try to install either one of the above, there's also dependencies and can't complete the installation.

---

**Edit 2**

**lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e1 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable SoftSailing
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0341 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0951:1665 Kingston Technology Digital DataTraveler SE9 64GB
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
23:00.0 System peripheral: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller (rev 30)
23:00.2 SD Host controller: JMicron Technology Corp. Standard SD Host Controller (rev 30)
24:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
```

---

**Edit 3**

From Edit 1, after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27794125/7109869), I have tried using

```
rpm -ihv $PackageName
```

Instead of `-Uhv`. And when running

```
rpm -ihv NetworkManager-libnm-1.22.8-5.el8_2.x86_64.rpm
```

I am getting the following

```
warning: NetworkManager-libnm-1.22.8-5.el8_2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 8483c65d: NOKEY
Verifying...                          ################################# [100%]
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
    file /usr/lib64/libnm.so.0.1.0 from install of NetworkManager-libnm-1:1.22.8-5.el8_2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package NetworkManager-libnm-1:1.22.8-4.el8.x86_64
```

---

**Edit 4**

As per Artem S. Tashkinov's suggestion, I have reenabled cache, went to my machine that is connected with the Internet (it uses Windows), downloaded the packages [kmod-wl-6.30.223.271-32.el8.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/rpmfusion-nonfree-updates-x86_64/kmod-wl-6.30.223.271-32.el8.x86_64.rpm.html) and [rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm](https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm), added them to a USB stick and plugged it to the CentOS machine.

Over there I have changed the directory to the USB stick and ran

```
rpm -ihv rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm
```

Which got me the following

```
warning: rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID bdda8475: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    epel-release >= 8 is needed by rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8-0.1.noarch
    rpmfusion-free-release >= 8 is needed by rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8-0.1.noarch
```

And ran

```
rpm -ihv kmod-wl-6.30.223.271-32.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Which retrieved the following

```
warning: kmod-wl-6.30.223.271-32.el8.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID bdda8475: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    kmod-wl-4.18.0-147.el8.x86_64 >= 6.30.223.271-32.el8 is needed by kmod-wl-6.30.223.271-32.el8.x86_64
```

Comment: Please post `lspci` and `lsusb` output at first. CentOS 8 contains quite an old kernel and firmware is old as well which could mean that your newer HW is not supported.

Comment: You have a gigabit ethernet card. Byte the bullet and bootstrap the system via a cabled connection first. So much easier. The alternative is mounting a DVD iso as an extra repository, but again, I advise against it if you can put that ethernet connection to work. I also do not advise minimal installations for people not used to be sysadmins in Unix systems.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I know that. The problem is [similar to this one](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4302461). However that was a big constraint as everyone here were working using Wi-Fi and the only ethernet cable available is connected to the router.

Comment: Get another ethernet cable and connect to the router, take it home, connected it to an wifi->ethernet adapter....It seems you are making excuses. It is up to you whether you prefer to deal with bureaucracy finding a wired connection, or spend 1 week trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just followed @RuiFRibeiro's suggestion and got an Ethernet cable. With it, the process was way faster as it required a variety of packages with various dependencies.

Apart from [Artem S. Tashkinov's suggestions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613403/226215), that didn't solve my issue (`dnf install kmod-wl` this one was giving me dependencies errors), I ran

```
sudo dnf install kernel
```

Then

```
sudo yum install NetworkManager-tui

chkconfig NetworkManager on

service NetworkManager start
```

Then

```
sudo yum update
```

And finally

```
sudo yum install akmod-wl
```

Some of the threads I have followed:

. [How to connect to wifi in CentOS 7(CLI)(no GUI)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370318/how-to-connect-to-wifi-in-centos-7clino-gui)
. [Wireless Adapter (WiFi) not working and not showing up in settings](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4302461#comment-1578671)
. [BROADCOM wireless drivers](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4058171)

Answer (score 0):

You have a BCM43228 wifi network adapter.

You have to enable the RPMFusion Nonfree repo and install `kmod-wl`. This unfortunately requires a working Internet connection:

```
rpm -ivh https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/el/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-8.noarch.rpm
dnf install kmod-wl
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without Internet access (I do not have Ethernet access)? I do, however, have access to on another machine and can download things from there, put it on an USB stick and install in this new machine.

Comment: Reenable caching in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf  keepcache=1` (disabled by default), run the above commands, copy the RPM files from `/var/cache/dnf`, `rpm -ivh *.rpm` all of them on your PC.

Comment: Couldn't make it work, as per Edit 4. You were assuming that my PC ("your PC") was based on Unix and I have followed the approach you suggested on my Windows machine. I am currently downloading the dependencies and will try to install all of them and redo the procedure (with the dependencies already installed) to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
[nik@dlin1 ~]$ lspci -k|grep Network

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566MM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation **PRO/Wireless 4965** AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection (rev 61)
```

Then I downloaded `iwl4965-firmware.noarch`
and installed it with:

```
sudo dnf install iwl4965-firmware.noarch
```

To see the effect, I had to reboot.